# How to solve itext image get instance network on main thread issues?

Tags: android, itext

I want to add image to pdf from android using itext library, but when i use `Image.getInstance("https://amp.thisisinsider.com/images/5ad8ba5cbd967118008b462c-960-720.jpg");` to add image, it produce network on main thread exception. The tutorial use this code to add image. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you should really have that http request happen in a background thread. Android is basically telling you with the exception, that you are making a request on the main thread, which will block your application/UI.

Maybe you should consider wrapping that code in an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Answer (score -1):

Solved using this code, put this code before getInstance

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```